# Convert Int to String while decoding JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I want to decode this JSON to a normal-looking Struct or Class but I'm facing a problem that I need to create a whole new Struct for property age, how can I avoid that and save age Directly to class Person?

Also, it would be good to convert Int to String

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": {
                    "age_years": 29
           }
}

struct Person: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var age: Age
}

struct Age: Decodable {
    var age_years: Int
}
```

I want to get rid of Age and save it like:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
        var name: String
        var age: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let name,age: String
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
          case name, age
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        do {
            let years = try container.decode([String:Int].self, forKey: .age)
            age = "\(years["age_years"] ?? 0)"
        }
        catch {
            let years = try container.decode([String:String].self, forKey: .age)
            age = years["age_years"] ?? "0"
        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead." Got this error

Comment: may be change `[String:Int].self` to `[String:String].self`

Comment: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead." :(

Comment: Is the `age_years` fields sometimes an Int and sometimes a String? That complicates things, but you could try both:

```
do {
            let years = try container.decode([String: Int].self, forKey: .age)
            age = "\(years["age_years"] ?? 0)"
        } catch {
            let years = try container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: .age)
            age = "\(years["age_years"] ?? "0")"
        }
```

Comment: here's list of age_years that i grabbed using additional Struct for Price as i mentioned above: Age(age_years: 299.0)
Age(age_years: 9.99)
Age(age_years: 0.0)
Age(age_years: 19.88)
Age(age_years: 0.0)

Comment: @fguchelaar it's actually a Double, but changing it to [String: Double] in your approach doesn't help too :(

Comment: @fguchelaar "Expected to decode String but found a number instead."

Comment: @Uois2001 it’s probably best if you edit your question and add some more json samples so it gets clear for everyone what we are dealing with.

Comment: @Uois2001: I've edited the answer with a do/catch. That should fix your issue, but if it's doubles instead of ints, then change `[String: Int]` to `[String: Double]`

Comment: @fguchelaar I did change it to Double, but didn't work for me :(

Comment: @Uois2001 please update your question with latest tries and the current json response